# Is $A^k=A^t$ can happen?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let, $A$ is a non-symmetric matrix with real entries. Does there exist a natural number $k$ such that $A^k=A^t$ ($A^t=$ transpose of $A$).

To me, it looks like such $k$ might not exists, since $A^tA=A^k\cdot A=A^{k+1}$ is a symmetric matrix. Then $A$ must be symmetric matrix which contradicts that $A$ is a non-symmetric matrix. Is my argument correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not correct. The power of a non-symmetric matrix can be symmetric. Example: $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}^2=0$$

Comment: @ajotatxe: $A^2 \ne A^t$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does exist.

Consider
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}\cos 45&-\sin45\\\sin45&\cos45\end{pmatrix}$$
Then
$$M^7=\begin{pmatrix}\cos 315&-\sin315\\\sin315&\cos315\end{pmatrix}=M^t$$

The angles are in degrees.

Comment: Thanks, so can we have a formula or something like that to find $k$ ?

Comment: @user467365 In the case of rotation matrices it's easy as $R(\alpha)=R^T( -\alpha)=R^T( -\alpha+360^{\circ})$. It's sufficient to find such $k$ that $k\alpha= 360^{\circ}-\alpha $